# How to properly set Bootstrap's column classes to equal height

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Consider this markup:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-4">
    <img src="somesource.png">
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-6">
    <h1>Some text</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-2">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
  </div>
</div>
```

If the image is around `100px` in height and the rest is less. How are you supposed to properly set them to equal height without setting a hard coded valued `height` property on all of them?

The columns should be able to have `absolute` positioned elements inside them and still be equal height as the rest of the columns.

I tried writing a script for this, however, no matter what I did the height of the columns never got the correct value. The script looks like this:

```
var highest = 0,
    columns = $('.row').find('> div[class*="col"]');

$.each(columns, function() {

  var height = $(this).height();

  if (height > highest) {
    highest = height;
  }
});

$.each(columns, function() {
  $(this).css('height', highest + 'px');
});
```

However, this script seems to pick the lowest height and then apply that height to all the `.col`s.

Why isn't this working the way it should be? And isn't there a better way than doing it like this?

If possible, is there a pure CSS way of obtaining this behavior? Preferably **without** using table-like CSS rules.

Answer (score 2):

You can find the answer to that question in questions already answered in StackOverflow:

[Twitter Bootstrap 3 - Panels of Equal Height in a Fluid Row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20503064/twitter-bootstrap-3-three-panels-of-equal-height-in-a-fluid-row)

Or here:

[How can I make Bootstrap columns all the same height?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19695784/how-can-i-make-bootstrap-columns-all-the-same-height)

Comment: Ye I know but they're not really optimal, and none of them seem to deal with having images in the columns. The flex solution would seem the best, I found that having just display: -webkit-box; fixes the issue for chrome and safari but not IE and Firefox. As soon as I add display: flex; it breaks my images by squeezing them together. After looking over the solution I'd probably prefer a JS solution since none of the CSS ones seem to work properly. Which also brings me back to the original problem, why isn't my script working?