# Bootstrap - panels with same height and width

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, panel

I'm having a `div.row` that contains 3 panels with different contents:

```
<div class="row equal">

    <div class="col-md-4">
      <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-body">
          <h3>Title 1</h3>
          <p>This is a paragraph</p>
          <p>This is a paragraph</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-4">
      <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-body">
          <h3>Title 2</h3>
          <p>This is a paragraph</p>
          <p>This is a paragraph</p>
          <p>This is a paragraph</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-4">
      <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-body">
          <h3>Title 3</h3>
          <p>This is a paragraph</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

I'd like to set all panels to have the same height, no matter their content, like on this topic [Twitter Bootstrap 3 - Panels of Equal Height in a Fluid Row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20503064/twitter-bootstrap-3-three-panels-of-equal-height-in-a-fluid-row), so I have set my `.equal` class.

```
.equal, .equal > div[class*='col-'] {  
        display: -webkit-box;
        display: -moz-box;
        display: -ms-flexbox;
        display: -webkit-flex;
        display: flex;
        flex:1 1 auto;
}
```

The problem is that, although the height is set equal to all panels the width of each panel has changed, so now my panels don't have the same width (the default one).

Is there a way I can fix the width too, or maybe use another way to have in all my panels same width and height?

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aroxv143/)

Comment: By *(the default one)* you mean to `.panel` should occupy full `width` of `col-md-4` ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you want something like this:

Setting separated for ease of reference.

```
.equal {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
}

div[class*='col-'] {
  flex:1 1 auto;
  background: lightblue;
  display: flex;
}
.panel {
  flex:1 0 100%;
}
```

[**Codepen Demo**](http://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/wKvZrN)

Comment: This is not responsive

Comment: Yes...it is...check the Codepen demo.

Comment: I mean panels not stacking. Try to add more panels (e.g 4 X col-md-3) - you'll get horizontal scrollbar.

Comment: works like a charm. You saved me from lots of head scratching

Answer (score 1):

what if you set the height of the parent and all children with height of 100%?

```
.equal{
    height:200px;
}
.col-md-4, .panel{
    height:100%;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/aroxv143/1/